# How to move files into newly created directory on condition in shell/perl

Tags: shell, find, rename, perl

It was a mess of  music files and directory.

It is needed to perform the below operation over multiple directories at once:

1. If the directory contains ".jpg" files,  then create a new directory
      "Covers" and move those files into it.
2. If the directory does not  contain any ".jpg" files, don't create
      "Covers" directory
3. If the directory  already contains "Covers" directory, don’t create
      "Covers" directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for dir; do
    [[ -d $dir ]] || continue
    jpgs=( "${dir}"/*.jpg )
    if (( "${#jpgs[@]}" )); then
        [[ -d ${dir}/Covers ]] || mkdir "${dir}/Covers"
        # Avoiding race condition by not reusing the jpgs array
        for jpg in "${dir}"/*.jpg; do
            mv "$jpg" "${dir}/Covers"
        done
    fi
done
```

Comment: pretty simple and neat, @Chris-down :-)

Comment: @Chris-down, darn that is awesome :)

Comment: @Chirs Down, Awesome sir :)

Answer (score 2):

I am still a rookie but here is mine:

```
#!/bin/bash
current_directory=$(pwd)
#echo $current_directory
(find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*' ! -name '.*' -printf '%f\n')>filelist
number=$(find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*' ! -name '.*' -printf '%f\n' | wc -l)
for iteration in `seq $number`
do
    fname=$(head -1 filelist)
    sed 1d < filelist > filelist2
    mv filelist2 filelist
    cd "$fname"
    if [ -z $(ls | grep -i jpg) ]
    then echo "Doing nothing as there are no JPG files....."
    else
        total=$(ls -l|grep -i jpg | wc -l)
        mkdir -p Covers
        mv *.jpg Covers
        echo "Moved $total JPG Files....."
    fi
    cd "$current_directory"
done
```

Simply go into the main music directory and execute this script.

No need to pass any arguments

EDIT: It was sloppy before. It is sloppier now. But I think it will work.

Comment: Thanks its very nice, Same question for you too : How to get handle those directory names which contains spaces in its name

Comment: Oh. Nice catch. I'll work on it.

Comment: Do *not* parse ls, it is dangerous and will break easily. Use a glob. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Also, you need to quote `$current_directory`, or it will break if the path has spaces in.

Comment: @ChrisDown, Thanks! I tried to fix it with minimal usage of sed and awk (Since I am not proficient yet). Do you still think it will break?

Comment: Yes, it will. Don't parse ls!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash  

SAVEIFS=$IFS  
IFS="\n\b"  
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

#work in current dir if work path was not provided  
[ $# -eq 0 ] && search_path="." || search_path="$1"  


# files to be moved, more extensions can be added  
wildcard="*[jpg|JPG]"  


move_jpg() {  
    # create "Covers" if it doesn't exist  
    [ -d "$1/Covers" ] && echo -n " ... " || { echo -n " ...create Covers ";   mkdir "$1/Covers" }  

    mv "$1/$wildcard" "$1/Covers/$wildcard"  
    echo "... files moved"  
}  



for d in "$search_path/*/"; do  

    echo -n "testing <$d>   "  

    [ -e "$d/$wildcard" ] && ${move_jpg "$d"} || echo "...Not found <$wildcard>"  

done  



#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: Using command substitution with `find` will break very easily. Do not do it.

Comment: Instead of calling `find`, which will break on all kinds of file names, write `for d in "$search_path"/*/`; the final `/` restricts the matching to directories. I wonder where `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")` comes from (by the way, you can write this in a simpler way: `IFS=$'\n\b'`): what's the point in making backspace a field separator?

Comment: didn't know about trick with last slash, will use it, thanks.
of cause, IFS=$(echo ...) can be easily replaced to just assignement.
corrected.

Comment: "Using command substitution with find will break very easily"
don't understand this :(
how find can be broken in such situation?